# How to tile divs independently in grids regardless of the max size of of a div in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to tile an image like : [image: this]  What I end up with is :[image: this].
This is my HTML, CSS and JavaScript code:

```js
window.onload = newWindow ;

function newWindow() {
    var data = JSON.parse(phrases);
    console.log(data);

    for (let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
        let column = document.createElement("DIV"); 
        column.className = "column";
        let card = document.createElement("DIV");
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        card.className = "card";

        let theme =  `theme : ` + data[i].theme;
        let content = document.createTextNode(theme)
        card.appendChild(content);
        card.appendChild(br);

        var br1 = document.createElement("br");

        let sourceText = `sourceText : ` + data[i].sourceText;
        content = document.createTextNode(sourceText);
        card.appendChild(content);
        card.appendChild(br1);

        var br2 = document.createElement("br");

        let translation = `translation : ` + data[i].translation;  
        content = document.createTextNode(translation);
        card.appendChild(content);
        card.appendChild(br2);

        column.appendChild(card);
        document.getElementById("cards-container").appendChild(column);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.row{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
}
.column {
    margin: 10px;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f32f;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang>
    <head>
    <title>Greeting Cards</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Phrases.json"></script>
    </head>
 
    <body>
    <div id="cards-container" class="row">

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The data comes from an external `JSON` file which I successfully parsed.   **How can I adjust my CSS so that I can tile my `div`s in columns regardless of the maximum size of the `div` in a row like in the first image?**
**I need 3 columns.**
My question is strictly about positioning the elements like in the first image. I want a solution in vanilla JavaScript and/or JQuery and CSS and HTML and not any other frameworks like Bootstrap.

Comment: Maybe you should use https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Comment: @RogersSampaio I don't want to use any libraries except for `JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it on a grid personally.

Here was my approach. Just basic stuff, added two columns, and split the 2nd column in two as well. 
https://jsfiddle.net/v1wzk9cu/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Test Columns Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>

     <div id="header" class="header">Example Header</div>
        <div id="Wrapper">
     <div id="column1" class="column">
         <div class="note">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="note">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="note">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="note">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="note">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
     </div>

     <div id="column2" class="column">
            <div id="columnA" class="twoColumns">
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div id="columnB" class="twoColumns">
         <div class="noteCol2"><br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2"><br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="noteCol2">&nbsp;</div>
     </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the CSS

```
.column{
background-color: #FF3636;
float:left;

}

.twoColumns{
background-color: #FF3636;
float:left;
}

.note{
width: 95px;
background-color: #FFF34D;
border: 1px black solid;
margin: 3px;
padding: 10px;
}

.noteCol2{
width: 95px;
background-color: #FFF34D;
border: 1px black solid;
margin: 3px;
padding: 10px;
}

#Wrapper{
margin: auto;
max-width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a clean implementation. To much stuff has been done manually. If the data is dynamic then it will have a difficult time to adapt

Answer (score 0):

So I think the easiest solution would be flexbox, although a more robust solution is javascript with an algorithm that would calculate the spaces based on the desired columns.

I don't have access to your JSON, but below you will find a structure very similar to what you have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 01
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 01
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 01
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 01
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 01
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 02
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 03
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 04<br />
    Its bigger

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 05
    <br />
    Its bigger
    <br />
    Its bigger
    <br />
    Its bigger
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 06
    <br />
    Its bigger much bigger
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 07
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 08
    <br />
    Its bigger
    <br />
    Its bigger
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    This is a card 09
    <br />
    Its bigger
    <br />
    Its bigger
    <br />
    Its bigger
  </div>
</div>
```

With a little bit of css:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f32f;
    margin: 5px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

The flexbox will try to fill the vertical space and when there is no room it will break horizontally and try to fill vertically again and so on. So the grid will be based on the height of your wrapper div.
You can find a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rogerssampaio/yp6xqh3a/8/

Comment: I have updated my question. I need strictly **3 columns**.